# post command not rendering data in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, rspec

I have defined a controller Add. In controller i have defined a function (add_params)

```
def add_values
  ans = params[:first_element] + params[:second_element]
  render :json => {:result => ans}.to_json
end
```

in routes file i have declared     `post :add_params`
if i call   `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"first_element" : 3, "second_element" :2}'  http://localhost:8000/add/add_values`   it return `{"result":5}`

but when i tried to test in Rspec as

```
describe AddController, :type => :request do
  it "must return 5" do
    post "http://localhost:8000/add/add_values", {"first_element" : 3, "second_element" :2}.to_json
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["result"]).to eq "5"
  end
end
```

it gives error as

```
Failure/Error: expect(response["result_is"]).to eq 5
      expected: 5
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/controller/add_controller_spec.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

i am using rails 3.2.16 , ruby 2.1.5 , rspec 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty weird that you receive

```
Failure/Error: expect(response["result_is"]).to eq 5
```

if your expectation is

```
expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["result"]).to eq "5"
```

the parameters of expect function are different one each other.

You should receive an error like this

```
Failure/Error: expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["result_is"]).to eq "5"
```

Are you sure your expectation is not

```
expect(response["result_is"]).to eq 5
```

?

Comment: when i am trying to get content_mime_type, it returns nil

Comment: it is showing  error             /Users/rack//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load': /Users/rack_koh/rails_code/calculate/spec/controllers/add_controller_spec.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    :post :add_values ,format: 'json...
             ^
/Users/rack_koh/rails_code/calculate/spec/controllers/add_controller_spec.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...add_values ,format: 'json', first_element: 3
...                                          ^

Comment: actually add_values is a post command which is being hit by another app through http command

Comment: try to submit your post in this way `post :add_values, format: 'json', first_element: 3, second_element: 2` instead of `post "http://localhost:8000/add/add_values", {"first_element" : 3, "second_element" :2}.to_json`